# Cannot access jquery ajax responseText in a deferred object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to create a promise based on a ajax call to a web method.  Originally, I had it working using this method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname + "/LoadPage"
)}.done(function(data){
    //do some stuff
}).fail(function(){
    //do other stuff
});
```

Then I ran into the issue of needing to wait for something to load, before doing something else, so I decided to create a variable to hold the promise object.

```
var promiseObj = $.ajax({...});
```

Then create a named function to call

```
function someFunction(data){...}
```

get access to the response from the server

```
var someData = promiseObj.responseText;
```

and call it like

```
promiseObj.done(someFunction(someData));
```

and it didn't work.  I was getting undefined errors.

So I tried just to `console.log` it

```
console.log(promiseObj) //shows the object
console.log(promiseObj.responseText) //gives undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? How to I send the data from the ajax call to another function using this method?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just use `promiseObj.done(someFunction);`. Please have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, simply remove the function wrapper in the `.done` call - just call `.done(someFunction)`.  That will ensure that all of the parameters generated by the AJAX call are passed to `someFunction`.   It will also ensure that any `this` context set in the `$.ajax` call is passed correctly, too.

Having fixed that, the `jqXHR` object should be found passed as the third parameter to `someFunction`, so you can use that to access the `.responseText`.

```
function someFunction(data, status, jqXHR) {
    var text = jqXHR.responseText;
    ...
}

promiseObj.done(someFunction);
```

Comment: that is how I had I originally, and I was working fine.  I want to move that anonymous function into a named function.  `promiseObj.done(someFunction());`

Comment: @RobM See the new edit.  The way you've written it won't work as you've already called `someFunction()` instead of _passing_ `someFunction` to `.done`.